# Docusign Error while generating JWT Token

Tags: docusignapi

Error while requesting server, received a non successful HTTP code with response Body

Getting this exception while generating the token inside an API. when TLS 1.3 is enabled

Below is the token generation code:

```
 private static OAuth.OAuthToken GetToken(string _apiUrl, string _integratorKey, string _impUserID, byte[] privatekey, ApiClient apiClient)
 {
     OAuth.OAuthToken authToken = null;

     int expiesInHours = Int32.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["expiresInHours"]);

     var scopes = new List<string>
         {
             "signature",
           "impersonation",
         };

     authToken = apiClient.RequestJWTUserToken(
              //Integrator key
              _integratorKey,
              //userID
              _impUserID,
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OAuthBasePath"],
              privatekey, expiesInHours, scopes);
     return authToken;
 }
```

Wanted to know if tls 1.3 is supported?

Comment: It would be helpful to have the actual error body as it would point towards what went wrong with the request. Could you paste in the error body?

Answer (score 0):

For authentication to DocuSign using OAuth you must [grant consent](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/consent/). Even when using [JWT](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/jwt/) consent must be granted, at least once. Without consent you will get an error. To [grant consent you must use a web browser](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/consent/obtaining-individual-consent/) and login to DocuSign with the same account and user that you plan to get an access token for (the `_impUserID` must match the user you used to login to grant consent)

Build a URL like this - https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature%20impersonation&client_id=7c2b8d7e-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-cda8a50dd73f&redirect_uri=http://example.com/callback/ and paste it to your browser. Make sure to replace the client_id with the same value you have for `_integratorKey` and ensure that the redirect URI in the URL is configured in the [Apps and Keys page on DocuSign](https://admindemo.docusign.com/authenticate?goTo=appsAndKeys&_gl=1*4fa6as*_gcl_au*MzA2NDQxMzU2LjE2ODgxNTI3NjU.*_ga*NjgzODQ5MDIuMTY4ODE1Mjc2NQ..*_ga_1TZ7S9D6BQ*MTY5MzA2NjMzMC4yODcuMS4xNjkzMDY2NDUwLjU0LjAuMA..&_ga=2.258240650.1494436946.1692637162-68384902.1688152765).